# What is the equivalent of the Visual Studio "Peek Definition" feature in MATLAB?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, visual-studio-2012, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I am searching for the equivalent of https://dailydotnettips.com/peek-definition-in-visual-studio-2013-is-now-all-about-ctrl-click/ in MATLAB? It's extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there it is not similar but exist a kind of tricks that help to trace functions. might help. [Moving between functions](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/03/23/moving-between-functions-within-a-file/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Peek definition" window in MatLab, but here's a couple of tricks that may help:

- Press <kbd>F1</kbd> for help on some function, in case you forgot which arguments you must use for the current function.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Open Selection) for reaching the code of any function to reach it's code. Works with the vast majority of functions of MatLab which are written in normal MatLab code.